# Get the last Date record from a date range if falls below a certain value

Tags: sql, date

I have query where it gets a list of employees and the most recent date where they fall below a 30 hour work week.

```
SELECT T1.Employee, T1.Date, T1.Hours
FROM EmployeeHours T1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT Employee, MAX(Date) AS MAXDATE
            FROM EmployeeHours WHERE Hours < 30 GROUP BY Employee) T2
 ON T1.Employee = T2.Employee AND T1.Date = T2.MAXDATE
 GROUP BY T1.Employee, T1.Date, T1.Hours
```

What I would like is to see if I can get the the most recent date in a date period if the employee falls below 30 hours in a 12 week period

I guess my biggest issue here is a 12 week period from what? I guess a start date would be best, but I'm not sure how to implement that with a `DATEADD()` here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
    SELECT T1.Employee, T1.Date, T1.Hours
    FROM Employee T1 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT Employee, MAX(Date) AS MAXDATE
                FROM Employee 
                WHERE DATEADD(Day,-12, GETDATE()) <= Date AND DATEADD(Day,0,GETDATE()) > Date
                GROUP BY Employee) T2
     ON T1.Employee = T2.Employee AND T1.Date = T2.MAXDATE
             GROUP BY T1.Employee, T1.Date, T1.Hours
```

Comment: I think so! Although it was for weeks and not days, but that's easily changed. I'm going to go over it to understand the logic of having the AND Greater than in the where clause though, but the data it yields does seems to be right, thanks again.

Comment: You can also use parentheses in WHERE, i.e.
WHERE (DATEADD(Day,-12, GETDATE()) <= Date AND DATEADD(Day,0,GETDATE()) > Date) AND Hours < 30

will group the date range together and then the hours criteria.

Comment: Further looking into it, it turns out what I should be looking at is a rolling date for every -12 weeks. I don't know how I will address that. Right now I have a sql function that's just checking the 2 most recent dates where there's less than 30 hours and if there difference is 12 weeks or less and if so that will get what I need, but it's a function and running that on large data sets of course hurts performance. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Since it's 12 weeks instead of days, you could change 'Day' to 'Week' in the DATEADD function.

Comment: No, I understand that, I didn't explain my question correctly because quite frankly, I did not know what I was looking for myself.

Comment: No prob - I know that feeling